# Define project Url with maven

Tags: maven, url

how can i define different url for maven project on tomcat and other application server?

For example for a project that have this properties:

```
<groupId>org.tutorial</groupId>
<artifactId>MyTutorial</artifactId>
```

hi have that the URL is:

> localhost:8080/MyTuorial

How can i have the following Url?

> localhost:8080/myfirstchangenametutorial.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

`Maven` artifact id has nothing to do with your project `url`, you need to update change your application `context`.
Different application servers have different ways to `provide` the application context.
e.g

For Jboss, you need to modify your jboss-web.xml
something like.

```
  <jboss-web>
  <context-root>somepath/Myapp</context-root>
  </jboss-web>
```

Weblogic, uses `weblogic.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i meant something like this: <warName>myApp</warName> in configuration of maven-war-plugin